# Run shell script on Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jobs, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I have an oracle database:

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

and I would like to run my script stored on db server.

```
path: /d01/oracle/scripts/super_skripta.sh
```

The content of my script (test script):

```
IME=$(date +"%s")

touch /d01/oracle/scripts/$IME
```

Can someone explain me (step by step) how can I run this script from a oracle database?

I tried to create an executable program like this:

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_program
(
program_name => 'SUPER_SKRIPTA',
program_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
program_action => '/d01/oracle/scripts/super_skripta.sh',
enabled => TRUE,
comments => 'super skripta'
);
end;
/
```

and then create a job:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"WOLFY"."JOB_SS"',
            program_name => '"WOLFY"."SUPER_SKRIPTA"',
            start_date => NULL,
            repeat_interval => NULL,
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '',

            job_style => 'REGULAR');




    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"WOLFY"."JOB_SS"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);



    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"WOLFY"."JOB_SS"');
END;
```

but it does not work...

Comment: "it does not work". Are we expected to guess what does not work ? Please explain what exactly "does not work" means as well as the debugging steps you already took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment:

```
[oracle@o61 ~]$ ls -l /home/oracle/myscript*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 44 Mar 25 17:38 /home/oracle/myscript.sh
[oracle@o61 ~]$ cat /home/oracle/myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/oracle/myscript.out
[oracle@o61 ~]$

[oracle@o61 ~]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin/extjob*
-rwsr-x---. 1 root   oinstall 1254574 Nov  1 21:01 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extjob
-rwx------. 1 oracle oinstall 1254574 Nov  1 21:01 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extjobo
-rwsr-x---. 1 root   oinstall 1254292 Oct 19 14:54 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extjobO
-rw-------. 1 oracle oinstall 1254292 Oct 19 14:54 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extjoboO

[oracle@o61 ~]$ grep -v "^#" $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/externaljob.ora

run_user = oracle
run_group = oinstall
```

Then create a job that is executed once then dropped:

```
[oracle@o61 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Mar 25 17:42:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job
  (
    job_name => 'RUN_SCRIPT',
job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
job_action => '/home/oracle/myscript.sh',
enabled => true,
auto_drop => true
  );
end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@o61 ~]$ ls -l /home/oracle/myscript.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  0 Mar 25 17:42 /home/oracle/myscript.out
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 44 Mar 25 17:38 /home/oracle/myscript.sh
[oracle@o61 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

## STEP 1 - Ensure that the file *can* be ran by the Oracle Database

The file mentioned by the parameter `job_action` is ran as the account that runs the Listener (usually *oracle*).

The OS **must** determine that said account can execute the program. The Read and Execute bits must be set on the file in such a way that the account can read and execute the file.  The account also needs the ability to access the file's directory (in some cases, all parent directories).  All other OS limitations are also applied.

For Security reason, all environment variables, including `PATH`, are cleared prior to executing that file.  `PATH` is set to a minimal value (RTFM). But, it is safer to assume that it doesn't exist.
This also means that programs such as `touch` could potentially throw an error because it it not in the new `PATH`.  I recommend that all Shell Scripts **must** either explicitly define `PATH` or explicitly call a program (eg `/usr/bin/touch`).

`sysexecv` (a C/C++ command) will only run a Shell Script when the file defines the Shell. That is: the first line **must** be a she-bang ( `#!`) line.

Also, you should keep the executable separate from any parameters for that executable.
eg use `/usr/local/bin/myapp` with 2+ parameters instead of `/usr/local/bin/myapp -p 20` with 0+ parameters

## Step 2 - create DBMS_SCHEDULAR entry

out-of-scope for this HOWTO

## Step 3 - Collect Errors

If you still have problems, you **must** provide all oracle errors encountered and all relevent log entries in addition to the DDLs for creating the entry and a copy of the script itself.

With out that information, posts that explain

> it doesn't work

are about as informative as

> my car is broken.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. I edited my script based on your step 1 and than used the other answer to create a procedure that runs my script. About step 3.. I'm still learning to collect errors from oracle, next time I will do better :)